# How to share a hotspot VPN from Android to PC (Windows)?

Tags: android, windows, vpn, hotspot

I'm struggling. I want to be able to use my laptop connected to the VPN of the hotspot of my mobile.

In this case, from my mobile I used the NordVPN app, selected a country, created a hotspot then connected my laptop to the hotspot, Internet works but the IP shows the country I'm based, not the one of the VPN.

I also tried Every Proxy app, failed.

I tried to manually set up the VPN on Android, failed.

Important: I can't install any app or software on my laptop.

Please help! And thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [Proton VPN's Android help page](https://protonvpn.com/support/share-vpn-connection-android-hotspot/):

> While sharing a VPN connection over a hotspot is technically possible, it usually involves modifying the Android operating system. To do this, you must be a tech-savvy user capable of “rooting” your Android device.

So it's sadly not as simple as "just get it through the VPN"